# Distinct Select with condition

Tags: sql

I'm removing duplicates of DatabaseID by using `Select Distinct DatabaseID`. However, some of rows have email address at the last column, `ContactEmail`, while most rows don't.

`Select Distinct DatabaseID` only exclude the duplicates without `ContactEmail`, while rows with `contactEmail` still have two `databaseID`. Specifically, there are two same database, and one with the contact email while another one doesn't.

```
   Select Tbl.DatabaseID, Tbl.TradingAccount, Tbl.FundManager
     ,Case When Tbl2.Dept = 'Rates Confirmation' Then Tbl2.ContactEmail Else '' END AS ContactEmail
    From TblMaster_Account as Tbl
    JOIN tblMaster_AcctContact as Tbl2
    ON Tbl.DatabaseID = Tbl2.DatabseID
```

I would like to also remove the duplicates with ContactEmail so that duplicated data without ContactEmail would join to the one with the ContactEmail

Current table looks like:

[image]

I want :

[image]

Comment: .... group by ContactEmail??

Comment: no it says "'DatabaseID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @BookOfZeus no it says "'DatabaseID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: oh yes, thanks Just understood what you meant

Comment: can you share your schema

Comment: please see the updated version

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below would be the query -

```
SELECT Tbl.databaseid, 
       Tbl.tradingaccount, 
       Tbl.fundmanager, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN Tbl2.dept = 'Rates Confirmation' THEN Tbl2.contactemail 
             ELSE '' 
           END) AS ContactEmail 
FROM   tblmaster_account AS Tbl 
       JOIN tblmaster_acctcontact AS Tbl2 
         ON Tbl.databaseid = Tbl2.databseid 
GROUP  BY Tbl.databaseid, 
          Tbl.tradingaccount, 
          Tbl.fundmanager
```

if your database supports analytical function then.

```
SELECT databaseid, 
       tradingaccount, 
       fundmanager, 
       contactemail 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   tl.databaseid, 
                         tl.tradingaccount, 
                         tl.fundmanager, 
                         t2.contactemail, 
                         Row_number() OVER (partition BY tl.databaseid, tl.tradingaccount, tl.fundmanager ORDER BY
                         CASE 
                                  WHEN t2.dept='Rates Confirmation' THEN t2.contactemail 
                                  ELSE '' 
                         END) AS rnk 
                FROM     tblmaster_account t1 
                JOIN     tblmaster_acctcontact t2 
                ON       ( 
                                  tl.databaseid = t2.databseid;)) WHERE rnk=1
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but what if ContactEmail was made by Case When Then As?

Comment: Yes, you can use case as well, updated the query using case

Comment: in my case, ContactEmail column actually came from the table which was joined by JOIN function. I just updated my code, feel sorry for the repetitive work Vijiy

Comment: Select Tbl.DatabseID, Tbl.TradingAccount, Tbl.FundManager
  ,CASE WHEN Tbl2.Dept = ‘Rates Confirmation’ Then Tbl2.ContactEmail Else ‘’ END AS ContactEMail
 FROM TblMaster_Account   as  Tbl
 JOIN tblMaster_AcctContact   as Tbl2
 ON Tbl.DatabaseID = Tbl2.DatabaseID

Comment: Changed the query by adding join

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggregate function.

```
Select
   Tbl.DatabaseID, 
   Tbl.TradingAccount, 
   Tbl.FundManager,
   MAX(Case When Tbl2.Dept = 'Rates Confirmation' Then Tbl2.ContactEmail Else '' END)AS ContactEmail
From TblMaster_Account as Tbl
JOIN tblMaster_AcctContact as Tbl2
ON Tbl.DatabaseID = Tbl2.DatabseID
GROUP BY  
    Tbl.DatabaseID, 
   Tbl.TradingAccount, 
   Tbl.FundManager
```